Aligning definition of terms of a sequence
I am trying to align the definition of the terms of a sequence: there are three possibilities.
I have tried the following:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$$
z_k=\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&x_k,\quad &1\leq k\leq N\\
&\lambda^{-n}y_{k-n},\quad &n+1\leq k\leq n+M\\
&0,\quad &n+M< k 
\end{aligned}\right.$$


\end{document}

But it looks off, the inequalities on the right are not aligned properly. Any help?

alignment points are marked with & and you don't have any by an inequality symbol.

@DavidCarlisle I have already tried putting them by the symbols but it did not work.

perhaps not (you probably want alignedat not aligned), but at least they would be aligned even if incorrectly spaced. as it is they are simply not aligned as no alignment has been specified.


You need to mark the alignment points on the inequalities with &, then use alignedat rather than aligned so that extra space is not inserted between the columns, and finally $$ is not supported syntax in LaTeX, so I changed that to \[.
In general for this sort of alignment you want alignedat but in this case as the middle column is all k so naturally the same width you could just align the first inequality, and use alignd as shown in the second block.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

alignedat
\[
z_k=\left\{
  \begin{alignedat}{3}
&x_k, &1&\leq k&&\leq N\\
&\lambda^{-n}y_{k-n},\quad &n+1&\leq k&&\leq n+M\\
&0, &n+M &< k&&
\end{alignedat}\right.
\]


aligned
\[
z_k=\left\{
  \begin{aligned}
&x_k, &1&\leq k\leq N\\
&\lambda^{-n}y_{k-n},\quad &n+1&\leq k\leq n+M\\
&0, &n+M &< k
\end{aligned}\right.
\]


\end{document}


I'd use array:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\[
z_k=\left\{
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
  \begin{array}{l @{\qquad} r >{{}}c<{{}} c >{{}}c<{{}} l}
  x_k,                 & 1   &\leq& k &\leq& N \\[1ex]
  \lambda^{-n}y_{k-n}, & n+1 &\leq& k &\leq& n+M \\[1ex]
  0,                   & n+M &<&    k
\end{array}
\right.
\]

\[
z_k=
\begin{cases}
  x_k,                 & 1\leq k \leq N \\[1ex]
  \lambda^{-n}y_{k-n}, & n+1 \leq k \leq n+M \\[1ex]
  0,                   & n+M < k
\end{cases}
\]

\end{document}

With >{{}}c<{{}} I specify a column for relation symbols, TeX will add the correct spacing by itself. Setting \arraycolsep to zero avoids intercolumn paddings.
I added the second version to show that alignment of k isn't really necessary, but it's a matter of personal taste, so I'm not saying your alignment is wrong: to my eye it's rather unbalanced.
Avoid $$ in LaTeX: Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?

Exploiting the particular situation, the first alignment can be done a bit more easily
  \begin{array}{l @{\qquad} r >{{}}c<{{}} l}
  x_k,                 & 1   &\leq& k \leq N \\[1ex]
  \lambda^{-n}y_{k-n}, & n+1 &\leq& k \leq n+M \\[1ex]
  0,                   & n+M &<&    k
\end{array}

